# Custom events in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, events

I am experimenting with custom events in Qt Creator. I am currently examining this example code on another site:

```
bool MyClass::event(QEvent* e)
{
    if (e && e->type() == MyCustomEventType) {
       MyCustomEvent* ce = dynamic_cast<MyCustomEventType*>(e);
       return handleCustomEvent(ce);
    }
    // very important: still handle all the other Qt events!
    return QObject::event(e);
}
```

The conditional statement checks if the event passed is the custom event, then it executes code that it wants to happen when the event occurs. What I do not understand is `return handleCustomEvent(e)` (what is this function supposed to do and where is it supposed to be declared?) and what `return QObject::event(e)` does. From what I read on the Qt documentation, the only thing this function does is return whether the event's function (is this handleCustomEvent?) is "recognized and processed". Is this supposed to handle all other events in the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handleCustomEvent()` is the method you need to implement in your class `MyClass` which will process your *Custom Event* `MyCustomEventType`.

If it's not your custom event, the last line `return QObject::event(e);` will be called to handle other events type.

So the method in your snippet `bool MyClass::event(QEvent* e)`, is acting like a routing code, to decide where to send the event for processing, and does not actually process the events.

Once decided that `'e'` is of type `MyCustomEventType` - it invokes `handleCustomEvent()` which will contain your code to handle this event type.
If not - the last line calls `QObject::event()` to process it instead. This will handle all other remaining types of events.
So, *no*, you need not worry about handling other events, unless you want to.

---

So, you'd declare the `handleCustomEvent()` in `MyClass` and implement it as well.
Something like:

```
class MyClass {
       ...
       ...
      public:
         bool handleCustomEvent(MyCustomEventType* e);
       ...
       ...
};
```

In the implementation you may have the logic as you require - to actually do the processing for your custom-event type `MyCustomEventType`.

Comment: So the last line, `QObject::event()` handles other events that are in the main loop? Unfortunately, the Qt documentation does not say anything about this. Also, for built-in Qt events (lets say mousePressEvent), if the mouse is pressed, does Qt automatically call the implementation (if given), QWidget::mousePressEvent()? Does this mean I shouldn't name the event handler something else (for built-in events)?

Comment: QObject::event() is a virtual function, thus all widgets implement this as part of their class, to provide a default behavior. In simple terms you may assume that it passes the event further up the chain - http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/qobject.html#event

Comment: So it's a virtual function, but in the code, I am calling QObject's version of event(). I was just wondering if this calls all the other events in the main loop containing the events.

Comment: `MyClass::event()` method is called for 'a' event, not 'events', i.e. it may be called multiple times for different/same event types, but a single invocation is for one event only. Thus, if it was called for an event which isn't of your custom type `MyCustomEventType` - The call to `QObject::event(e)` will take care of dispatching it to the correct handler.

Comment: Ohh, I see. For built-in Qt events (lets say mousePressEvent), if the mouse is pressed, does Qt automatically call the implementation (if given), QWidget::mousePressEvent()? Does this mean I shouldn't name the event handler something else (for built-in events)?

Comment: Yes, you will have to use the same name, by doing so you will override the method with your own implementation; That is how things work in C++, this is not specific to Qt - Look here http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but when working with a function handleCustomEvent(), should it be declared as return type bool? Its counterparts such as mousePressEvent() or keyPressEvent() have a void return type?

Comment: Basically it depends; But the virtual method `event()` that we are overriding need to return `true/false` to indicate we processed the event: http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/qobject.html#event . So as per the snippet in your question we are leaving the final decision to be handled inside `handleCustomEvent()`, and thus the method needs to have a `bool` return type.